# Java and stdin vs a file

Tags: java, input

I have to do this assignment but the thing says "All the programs should take input from STANDARD INPUT, not from a file." , this is fine to ask advice on, but what does this mean?

I was doing the code below but then someone said this is not correct, that its as if someone typed on the cmdline not a redirection from a file. I'm confused here, how do I do this so its stops when whoever tests my code gives it data, of while I don't know how they will other than stdin? Thanks, the data gets rather large like 500k.

```
    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

    /*
     * Get the data from the stdin and read into a buffer until its done.
     */
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s;
    try {
        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null && s.length() != 0) {
            double myReal = Double.parseDouble(s);
            // System.out.println(myReal);
            list.add(myReal);
            // System.out.println(s);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It means that your program should read from `System.in`, like you are already doing in your code (and not from a file).

Comment: Standard input is typing manually into the console. File input is the system does the reading from a file.

Comment: @Compass System.in could be redirected from a file.

Comment: " if someone typed on the cmdline not a redirection from a file" I am confused too as it is very hard to tell the difference. System.in is the same whether you read from console or redirected from a file by design.

Comment: @PeterLawry I am interpreting the instructions, which explicitly exclude file, as my definition =.=

Comment: IMHO your code is correct. "Reading from the command line" doesn't necessary mean that someone will type the 500k data manually. In UNIX you can easily pass files to program through "Standard Input". The teacher probably want to do so, that's why he is asking you to use it.

Comment: Yes I assumed they would do this myprog.jar < thedata.txt but when I don't feed it a file and just type I don't know how to stop the input, I tried cntrl-d and it crashes.

Comment: @Dixon Steel: can't you stop the program by a new line - return?

Comment: No, it should read each data point followed by a new line until it receives an end of file. But I spoke with someone else who said it should work with just typing to, but mine doesn't when I send cntl-d but this is on a windows machine not Linux, not sure it that's why.

Comment: Seems you are all right, I tested on Linux and it works with file re-direct and cntl-d for hand input.